# Automatically Change Security For Multiple PDF's In Acrobat 9 Pro

Tags: pdf

I'm using Acrobat 9 Pro and i have like 100+ .pdf files which i need to add security settings to them.
I saw tutorials for Acrobat X Pro but nothing for 9 Pro.
Is there any way to do this Automatically instead one file at a time?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Acrobat 9, you have Batch sequences, where you can set the security. [This Adobe Blog entry](http://blogs.adobe.com/acrobatforlifesciences/2010/04/removing_security_from_pdfs_in/) is a description on how to remove security, but setting so has the same steps and uses the same batch elements.

Answer (score -3):

You can get this program from my blog to do the exactly what you want.

https://hwinnapp.wordpress.com/2016/07/14/encrypts-all-your-pdf-files-with-the-same-password/